# Laravel - Testing - assertJsonMissingExact

Tags: laravel, laravel-testing

I have to admit that it's the first time I use this method

Before the description, here is the Laravel and PHP version in this case.
Laravel: 8.15
PHP: 7.4.13

- My Route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3];
```

- When my testing method was as follows, it failed, it's what I expected

```
    public function testDemo()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/')->assertJsonMissing(['a' => 1, 'b' => 3]);
    }
```

- And then, I used assertJsonMissingExact, and I expected it would pass.

```
    public function testDemo()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/')->assertJsonMissingExact(['a' => 1, 'b' => 3]);
    }
```

- However, it didn't pass. Instead, here is the message

```
This test did not perform any assertions

Time: 00:00.178, Memory: 20.00 MB


OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Risky: 1.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

It says that the test didn't perform any assertion. I'm wondering if it's normal? Because I'm expecting a `passed` result.

Anyone could help me with that will be so much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Might be too late for you, but maybe not for the next person (like me) who wanted to understand the two methods.

looking at the base implementations of the two

**Illuminate/Testing/AssertableJsonString::assertMissing()**
In simplified code (left out sorting of arrays)

```
public function assertMissing(array $data, $exact = false)
{
    $actual = json_encode($actualData);

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (Str::contains($actual, $unexpected){
           PHPUnit::Fail()
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

**Illuminate/Testing/AssertableJsonString::assertMissingExact()**

In simplified code

```
public function assertMissing(array $data, $exact = false)
{
    $actual = json_encode($actualData);

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (! Str::contains($actual, $unexpected){
           return $this;
        }
    }

    PHPUnit::Fail()
}
```

Therefore, assertJsonMissing fails if the whole array is in the actual data, while assertJsonMissingExact fails if at least one key => value pair is in the actual data, in your case `'a' => 1`